# getting alexa rank but file_get_content is not working in live server in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

My code

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=google.com');
print_r($source);
//Alexa Rank
preg_match('/\<popularity url\="(.*?)" text\="([0-9]+)" source\="panel"\/\>/si', $source, $matches);
$aresult = ($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : 0;
```

but `print_r($source)` won't display the data.

Comment: If you output `'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$row['domainName']` and execute that link does it work? If you curl it from your server does it work? (Unrelated but `<`, `>`, and `=` are not special characters in regex. They don't need to be escaped. The `/` also isn't special, except in this case because you have chosen it to be the delimiter (so keep that escaped)).

Comment: Okay, when I load `http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=google.com` I get a response but it looks like curling it fails.

Comment: so, why is print_r($source) won't display the data. can you help this coding?

Comment: What does http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php give back?